# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 77

Tags: maven, selenium-chromedriver

Following Chrome browser being updated to version 79, I am having this error every time I try to create ChromeDriver.

This is what I have in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there a specific value I need to use, to be able to create a ChromeDriver instance?
I couldn't find any useful indication here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver
Until about a week ago, I used the value "3.141.59".